# SQL: how do you fetch a first day of the month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, toad

SQL: how do you fetch a first day of the month?

Hi,

I need to fetch a first day of every month from tbl.date from column start_date.

```
11/1/2017
12/1/2017
1/1/2018
2/1/2018
ETC.
```

Thanks

Comment: Which database is it

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: WHERE DAY( tbl.date ) = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution in ANSI SQL looks like this:

```
select dte - (1 - extract(day from dte)) * interval '1 day'
```

In SQL Server, this would be:

```
select dateadd(day, 1 - day(dte), dte)
```

Similar functionality is available in almost any database.

If you just want the rows that are first days of the month, then:

```
where extract(day from dte) = 1
```

In SQL Server, this would be:

```
where day(dte) = 1
```

Of course, the syntax might be different depending on the database.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using Postgres, in case you need to select the first row for each month, if there's no guarantee that that will be the first day of the month:

```
CREATE TABLE dates (
     id    BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
     date  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dates(date)
VALUES ('2017-05-05'::timestamp), ('2017-05-02'::timestamp), ('2017-05-30'::timestamp), ('2017-05-25'::timestamp), ('2017-05-15'::timestamp), ('2017-05-01'::timestamp), ('2017-06-10'::timestamp), ('2017-06-02');

SELECT DISTINCT ON(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)) date
FROM dates
ORDER BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date), date ASC;
```

Results:

```
date
--------------------
2017-05-01T00:00:00Z
2017-06-02T00:00:00Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using Sql server

declare @FirstDOM date, @LastDOM datetime

```
set @FirstDOM = (select dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(mm,datediff(m,0,getdate()),1 )))

SELECT CONVERT( varchar, @FirstDOM,101);
```